# Hyper-V Integration Services - Guests stop reporting IP Addresses

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, monitoring, hyper-v

I have a few Windows guest VMs running on Hyper-V with Hyper-V Integration Services installed that will periodically stop reporting their IP Addresses to the host operating system, usually after running for a long period of time. i.e. when using the `Get-VMNetworkAdapter` command, the IPAddresses field is blank, and no IP Addresses show up in Hyper-V Manager under the "Networking" tab.

I know a reboot of the VM will fix the issue temporarily, but I am looking for a less disruptive solution. I have tried:

- stopping and starting each of the [Hyper-V Integration Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/integration-services) on the VM.
- Using the VM Settings on the host to disable and reenable each of the integration services.

I believe there is something getting stuck or hung in the [Hyper-V Data Exchange Service (KVP)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/integration-services#hyper-v-data-exchange-service-kvp), because when I test stopping and starting that service on a healthy VM, the networking information will go away and then come back. However, no amount of restarting this service has brought back the IP Address information.

I also know the KVP service is functioning because I can query the "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest" values on the guest from the host using WMI.

Versions Used:

- Host OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter - 6.3.9600
- Guest OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter - 6.3.9600
- Integrations Services: 6.3.9600.18692

Is there any way to force the VM to continue reporting the IP Address to the host other than a reboot?